# Determine if another rosnode is subscribing to published topic?

Tags: ros, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way for a publisher to check if another node is online and/or if the other node has established subscriptions to topics?  (C++).  I want to ensure that I don't send a configuration command if the subscriber has not yet subscribed.

I've seen this before that you can do this, but I don’t remember how.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46116/determine-if-another-rosnode-is-subscribing-to-published-topic?/) by [PerkinsJames](https://answers.ros.org/users/2621/perkinsjames/) on ROS Answers with karma: 506 on 2012-10-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`pub.getNumSubscribers() > 0`

Depending on your application, consider a latched publisher.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2